# Ocultar texto de carrito de compra en Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

En una pagina web con Woocommerce estoy tratando de ocultar
la palabra ITEMS. Estoy utilizando el widget de CART. La primera opción que se me ocurro era utilizar el estilo CSS

```
display:none
```

Pero al hacerlo también se desaparece la cantidad de productos. Existe alguna linea de codigo o endonde puedo modificar este Widget
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías inspeccionar el elemento y añadir a tu pregunta cómo es que está formado el `HTML` de esa parte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con javascript:

```js
// seleccionamos el elemento "a" que tenga un hijo directo "i" con class "wpmenucart-icon-shopping-cart-0"
   // seleccionamos a su hermano "span" con class "cartcontents"
let span  = document.querySelector("a > i[class='wpmenucart-icon-shopping-cart-0'] ~ span[class='cartcontents']");
   // obtenemos su texto y hacemos un split en base al espacio
   // obtenemos la posicion "0" que es el numero 
   // y se lo asignamos a la span ya formatedeado
span.innerText = span.innerText.split(" ")[0];
```

```html
 <a href="">
   <i class="wpmenucart-icon-shopping-cart-0"></i>
    <span class="cartcontents"> 2 items</span>
    </a>
```